# vue2-google-map fail to load library

Tags: javascript, google-api, vue-component

I want to load geocode library with vue2-google-map component in my app.js

```js
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps"
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
        key: <my_api_key>,
        libraries: "places,geocode", 
        language: 'en',
    }
})
```

at loading page I get `404` error

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/geocode.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

My api key is enabled to get geocode library, from browser the request below works.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<lat>,<lng>&key=<my_api_key>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was wrong to load geocode library in the initialization of component, to load geocode library I use $mapPromise method of component

```
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
       this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then(() => {
           let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
           let home = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
           geocoder.geocode({
               location: home
               }, 
          function(geocoderResults) {
              console.log('google result' , geocoderResults);
           });
       })
   });
```